# AKS nodepool vmSize upgrades vs nodepool delete

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli

I have a case where I want to perform an inplace upgrade of the AKS cluster node pools vmSize, deletion of the full cluster is not possible.

One alternative that I have looked into is to perform `az aks nodepool delete' and then recreate it with a new vmSize.
Question here is: What is really happening under the hood, drain all and delete?

Should we first drain all the nodes in sequence, and then run the command to achieve 0 downtime? We are running multiple node pools

Anyother suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont add a new node pool and migrate your workload to the new nodepool, then delete the old node pool.

You could also import this new node pool with Terraform if you use it.

Or is it the system node pool you are talking about?